Using cut command with criterion from a bash variable
I would like to use the cut command to extract some columns of a csv file.
However, instead of having my criterion hard-coded, I would like to take them from a bash variable.
Without a variable, my command would look like the following:
cut -d';' -f 1-8,20,22 "$input_file" > ANFR_reduced.csv

However, when I store the critera -f 1-8,20,22 within a bash variable, my cut command fails to execute correctly (error fields are numbered from 1)
criteria_col="-f 1-8,20,22"
cut -d';' "$criteria_col" "$input_file" > ANFR_reduced.csv

Any ideas to why this is not working, please?

Try: criteria_col=(-f 1-8,20,22), then cut -d\;  "${criteria_col[@]}"

Thanks @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub. This is indeed working, but I would have preferred not to have to store my criteria in an array as I take them from a text file :) . But thanks for your idea.

then read -ra criteria_col < textfile instead of criteria_col=$(<textfile)

capturing the data (from the file) in an array should be (relatively) easy; we'd just need to see a sample file and how you're currently populating criteria_col

-f and 1-8,20,22 are two separate arguments; you cannot supply them using a single quoted (regular) parameter expansion.

Another way is to simply remove douple quotes: cut -d';' $criteria_col "$input_file" > ANFR_reduced.csv. But I won't recommand this way!

The array is the correct solution. How you build that array from your input file is another question that needs to be answered.

BashFAQ #50, I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!, is directly on-point.

If you enable debug mode (set -xv) you'll see what bash sees:
$ touch some_file
$ criteria_col="-f 1-8,20,22"

$ set -xv

$ cut -d';' "$criteria_col"  some_file
+ cut '-d;' '-f 1-8,20,22' some_file
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cut: fields are numbered from 1
Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Notice that -f 1-8,20,22 is being treated as a single string '-f 1-8,20,22' which in turn causes the error.
One simple fix would be to move the -f from the variable to the command line, eg:
$ criteria_col="1-8,20,22"

$ cut -d';' -f "$criteria_col"  some_file
            ^^
+ cut '-d;' -f 1-8,20,22 some_file
$                                    # no error; no output since my file is empty

If you need the -f to be part of the criteria then I'd recommend  F.Hauri's comment/suggestion of using an array.
